# Shortcut to switching focus between editor and project tree(explorer) in CodeLite IDE

Tags: ide, codelite

Is there a shortcut to do - what I mention in topic, or some trick to simulate this in CodeLite IDE?

I know how to change tabs [CTRL+ALT+ARROW]

I found someone who looking the same:
https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues/1094

Right now I hack this by open new resources [SHIFT+CTRL+F], but I not satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no such shortcut. 
Please open a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues) or Submit a feature request

Eran